# wordpress multisite domain mapping redirects to original subdomain

Tags: multisite, apache, domain-mapping

This week I installed Wordpress 3.4.2 (Linux Centos + Apache2) and configured the network option using subdomains. Then I installed the MU Domain Mapping plugin, so I would be able to use it with domain names instead of subdomains. This works for one domain, however the second domain redirects to the subdomain.

- base site: multisites.com
- two subsites: one.multisites.com and two.multisites.com
- two new domains: one.de and two.com.de
- one.de works correct (based on one.multisites.com)
- two.com.de redirects to two.multisites.com

  - NB: two.com.de is a subdomain of com.de, and this is similar to the actual situation!

Two.com.de should not redirect. I don't see any differences in the setup. What could cause this and do you experience problems like this as well?

---

NB: I changed the domain names in the example to make it more clear.

Comment: Isn't `two.co.test` a sub-domain? I'd suggest you to use `example.com` and the likes, the fictitious names you're using are kind of confusing. I mean, one can get it, but has to read 2 or 3 times...

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusing domain names in the example. I use two.co.test because it actually is like that, so it's a subdomain from co.test, but that should not matter - or is this the cause of the problem? I will try with a third domain name: three.test! ;-)

Comment: I changed the domain names in the example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the Primary option is selected for the second domain under domain mapping settings. It should say Yes under Primary in Settings->Domains for that domain.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't realise that was about to which domain the site would redirect.